# Reactive element as filename in downloadHandler

Tags: r, shiny

How can I use an element from a reactive function as the filename in a downloadHandler? In this example, I enable the user to upload a .csv, a new column gets added to the data.frame, and then I want the user to be able to get back the modified data.frame as a .csv. If I hard-code the filename, it works as I expect. But I'd like the name of the returned file to be the same as the input file but with a suffix. Assigning the filename as one of the elements of the reactive function, `fileInfoFn`, returns gobbledygook, like '_tmp_Rtmp574nlm_5fcb74621d7eebf0d0ab5bb1_0.csv_mod.csv.'

```
ui <- fluidPage (
  helpText("Click here to upload file"),
  fileInput(inputId = "importedFile",
            label = NULL,
            accept = c(".csv"),
            buttonLabel = "Upload File",
            placeholder = "NA"),
  helpText("Click here to download output"),
  downloadButton(outputId = "exportedOutput",
                 label = "Download Output"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  fileInfoFn <- reactive ( {
    inFile <- input$importedFile
    if (is.null(inFile)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      file.rename(inFile$datapath,
                  paste(inFile$datapath, ".csv", sep=""))
      fileInfo <- list(
        outFile = paste0(inFile$datapath, "_mod.csv"),
        fileData = read.csv(paste(inFile$datapath, ".csv", sep=""))
      )
      return(fileInfo)
    }
  } )
  
  produceOutput <- reactive( {
    fileInfo <- fileInfoFn()
    if (length(fileInfo) > 0){
      dat4 <- fileInfo[["fileData"]]
      dat4$newColumn <- 1
    } else {
      dat4 <- data.frame(x = "noData")
    }
    return(dat4)
  } )
  
  output$exportedOutput <- exportedOutput <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      fileInfo <- fileInfoFn()
      if ("outFile" %in% names(fileInfo)) {
        outFile <- fileInfo[["outFile"]] # hard-coded value, like "userMod.csv," works
      } else {
        outFile <- "default.csv"
      }
      return(outFile)
    },
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(produceOutput(), file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage (
  helpText("Click here to upload file"),
  fileInput(inputId = "importedFile",
            label = NULL,
            accept = c(".csv"),
            buttonLabel = "Upload File",
            placeholder = "NA"),
  helpText("Click here to download output"),
  downloadButton(outputId = "exportedOutput",
                 label = "Download Output")
  ,verbatimTextOutput("t1")
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  fileInfoFn <- reactive ( {
    inFile <- input$importedFile
    if (is.null(inFile)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      # file.rename(inFile$datapath,
      #             paste(inFile$datapath, ".csv", sep=""))
      fname <- substr(inFile, 1, nchar(inFile)-4)
      return(list(
        outFile = paste0(fname, "_mod.csv"),
        fileData = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=TRUE, sep=",")
      ))
    }
  } )
  output$t1 <- renderPrint({fileInfoFn()$fileData})
  
  produceOutput <- reactive( {
    fileInfo <- fileInfoFn()
    if (length(fileInfo) > 0){
      dat4 <- fileInfoFn()$fileData
      dat4$newColumn <- 1
    } else {
      dat4 <- data.frame(x = "noData")
    }
    return(dat4)
  } )
  
  output$exportedOutput <-  downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      fileInfo <- fileInfoFn()
      if ("outFile" %in% names(fileInfo)) {
        outFile <- fileInfoFn()$outFile[1] # hard-coded value, like "userMod.csv," works
      } else {
        outFile <- "default.csv"
      }
      return(outFile)
    },
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(produceOutput(), file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```